# How to put java application on the web?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am writing a minesweeper program in Netbeans, with java. I would like my friends to be able to try it, preferably on from there own computer, over the web. I have already made a .jar file, but do not know if how to proceed, or even if this is possible. How would I put it on the web so they can try it out?

Comment: Email the .jar file to your friend, and have them start executing the .jar file just as you would on your computer.  If you want to create something that runs in the browser, you will probably need to make a lot of changes to your existing code.  Look into Java applets and Java Web Start at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/index.html

Comment: Email them your jar file. Otherwise, you should convert your app to an applet and post it in a HTML page on a Web Server, maybe you need a free web hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just send them the jar file? Then, they can just run it on their computer.

To put the program in a webpage, you need to put it in an applet, which will require some extra work (and maybe some changes to your code).

http://java.sun.com/applets/

Comment: *"To put the program in a webpage, you need to put it in an applet,"*  But to launch the app. from a link only requires JWS (and a frame).

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaWS (Java Web start )
Check this link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

Comment: Great idea!  But I find the [JWS info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) page here at SO is a better place to link, for explaining JWS.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to write your game as an Applet.

See the [standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or you can google for many others.